# Chronoforms 5 Date Picker in Multiplier Not Working

Tags: datepicker, chronoforms

I'm using Chronoform's 5 Multiplier feature which is triggerd with an 'Add Another Student' button. Prior to the Multiplier, I have two datepickers. Within the Multiplier are two datepickers. The first set of datepickers (prior to the Multiplier) pops up the calendar, as it should. Within the Multiplier, the calendar does not pop up.

Both datepickers have indpendent fieldIDs. After asking Chronoforms regarding this issue, the answer I received was:

"You'd have to add custom code to run when the Add button is clicked and attach the datepicker to the new...input then."

I'm not sure what this means.

Has anyone successfully been able to use Chronoforms 5 to get the datepicker to work within a Multiplier? Users can enter in a date manually, but that's not user-friendly. I would prefer to try to get this working.